# How to select more than one option in multiple selection list using jquery?

Tags: jquery

In my web application a method returns a list of array contains ID's of select options which should have to be selected. Its is hard to make them all selected using DOM methods.

Is there any way to do it using jQuery.

Any suggestions would be more appreciative...

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: @treeface - it's pretty clear what he wants...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on your comment below, your data looks the code below.

There's a problem. It is not valid for an HTML ID attribute to start with a number. IDs must begin with a letter.

I'll show you the solution anyway, but you should fix the IDs.

```
var array = [{respID:1, respName:null}, 
             {respID:2, respName:null}, 
             {respID:3, respName:null}, 
             {respID:4, respName:null}, 
             {respID:5, respName:null} 
             ];

$.each(array, function(i,val) { 
     $('#' + val.respID).attr("selected", "selected"); 
});
```

Now this will give you the value of `respID` in each iteration of the loop.

But again, HTML IDs can not start with a number. I'd suggest updating your HTML ID attributes to something like `id_5` instead of `5`.

```
<select>
    <option id="id_1" value="some value">some text</option>
    <option id="id_2" value="some value">some text</option>
    <option id="id_3" value="some value">some text</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Then you would do this:

```
$.each(array, function(i,val) { 
     $('#id_' + val.respID).attr("selected", "selected"); 
});
```

Comment: My List of array is like this 
  {respID:1, respName:null}, 
  {respID:2, respName:null}, 
  {respID:3, respName:null}, 
  {respID:4, respName:null}, 
  {respID:5, respName:null}
]

It is dynamically created in run time

Comment: I want to select them with the ID's

Comment: @MaRaVaN - OK, that's a little different. I'll update in a minute.

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery, you can just call `attr("selected", true)` on the collection of elements.  All you have to do is get the selector right:

```
$('#opt1, #opt2, #opt3').attr("selected", true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Actually selected doesn't take true/false, try it with "false" and it will still show as selected.

Comment: @Marko: If we were talking about attributes, you'd be correct.  However, jQuery's *attr()* function checks the first parameter to see if it is a valid property name and sets that first.  The *selected* property expects a boolean (true or false) and in this case "selected" would be an invalid value.  jQuery does this to work around issues with *setAttribute()* in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Marko - `false` does work :) Give it a try here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Qxhbw/

Comment: @Marko - I think your confusion comes from `"false"`, the *string* `"false"` is `true` in JS, while the boolean keyword `false` is actually `false`, so you need to pass it without quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Nick Craver and @Andy E: I learn something new every day.. :) All i was trying to say is that the HTML attribute selected can be left without a value, i.e. <option selected> or <option selected="selected"> as per http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_selected.asp If you add selected="false" it will still show as selected, see here http://jsfiddle.net/Qxhbw/1/

Comment: Cheers @Nick that definitely makes sense. I was just about to click "Add Comment" but thought I'd see what actually happens when you do .attr("anything", false).. and in your example, the class name gets changed to false (class="false"). Furthermore, if you do the same with an <option>, in Firebug the attribute doesn't get removed, in fact it doesn't change at all. Now I'm lost.

Comment: @Marko - Here's a bit better view of what's actually happening when you pass false: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Qxhbw/2/ I'm not sure why firebug shows the attribute as it does, but it is getting de-selected.

Comment: @Nick So in saying that, jQuery does a different thing for different attributes. setting .attr("class", false) changes the class name to "false", while setting .attr("selected", false) does **nothing** in Firebug, but it does deselect the option. It could also be the browser though.

Comment: @Marko - When doing a set it'll append do `"" + value` to normalize it, but only if it's not accessible in a DOM 0 way, e.g. `elem["attributeName"]`, then it rolls over to `.setAttribute("" + value)` which comes out as `"false"` in the example of a class.  It's more the browser handling these `= false` cases specially.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple, all you need to do is add an attribute of selected to the elements you want.

```
$("#id1, #id2", "select").attr("selected", "selected");
```

You can filter them by value too

```
$("option[value=someText]", "select").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply... Those multiple select select options are dynamically generated. The list of array comes like this... 
EmployeeManagement.getSelOptions(id, function(resp){// Jquery Code here...} The "resp" is the list array here....
How shall i use that single variable, i am have to iterate through any loop...???!!!! Thanks again

Comment: See @Patrick's and @Vadim's answer for looping through the id's

Answer (score 1):

If ids is an array of IDs, the following code should work:

```
$.each(ids, function() { $("#" + this).attr("selected", true); });
```