# Chosen plugin and multiple select

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have problem..
I using http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ and I would like select two value default, but 
I would like to use jQuery:

This is my code:

```
<select name="all[]" id="all" style="margin-left: 15px;" data-placeholder="All.." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="16">
<option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
<option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
<option value="Item 3">Item 3</option>
```

And my script:

```
$("#all").val('Item 2').trigger("chosen:updated"); <-- it work fine but I would like select more than 1 option...
```

Comment: See here ~> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613807/how-to-select-more-than-one-option-in-multiple-selection-list-using-jquery

Comment: I know how select normal <select> but this don't work in this situation

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Answer (score 0):

try this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4Wkm5/

Without any external plugin, you can use the following by adding class names to selected one.

```
$('.chosen-select option').each(function () {
    SelectElement(this);
});

function SelectElement(element) {
    $(element).addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: Okey :) But this add class ( class="selected") bu i would like add only: "selected" e.g. <option value="item" selected>item</option>

Comment: can you explain more... i did not get your comment. this will add class called "selected" to all options for demo purpose.

Comment: Your code gives me: <option value="item" class="selected">item</option> but i would like get: <option value="item" selected>item</option>

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an array to val instead:

```
$("#all").val(['Item1','Item 2']).trigger("chosen:updated");
```